# DBIx::Class and Searching

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I am trying to return today's birthdays. This is what I have right now, which works, but I need to grab the month and day to input into the statement. I thought maybe I could grab them from localtime, but that didn't work out. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
sub author_birth {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my ($day,$month) = (localtime())[3..4];
    my $author_result = $self->search_like(
        {
            birth => '%03-20'
        },
        {
            select => [
                'id',
                'complete_name',
            ],

            #result_class => 'DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator'
        }
    );

    my @author_ids = ();
    while (my $row = $author_result->next) {
        push @author_ids, $row->id;
    }

    return $self->get_author_info_by_id(\@author_ids);

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with `$day` and `$month` because they don't have the leading zeroes that the dates in your database include. The best solution (as you seem to have worked out already) is to use Time::Piece.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I wasn't even aware of Time::Piece until yesterday. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing something like this.

```
my ($self) = @_;
my $conc = '%';
my $datetime = Time::Piece->new->strftime('%m-%d');
my $date = $conc . $datetime;
my $author_result = $self->search_like(
    {
        birth => $date,
    },
    {
        select => [
            'id',
            'complete_name',
        ],

        #result_class => 'DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator'
    }
);
```